# Downloading/Buidling minecraft server jars using BuildTools in Bash/Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jar, minecraft

I am trying to write a bash/shell script for downloading BuildTools and compiling the jars with it, after that I want to move them to my webserver (`/var/www/html/jars/`) from within the script at `/home/buildtools/`

BuildTools downloads/compiles the jars and places them at the base directory, except the vanilla jar, which is located at `work/` inside the base directory.

Even though it does download/compile the jars, they aren't all moving to the desired directories.

This is the code I am using at the moment (I think it might all be relevant to provide):

```
directory="$(pwd)/"
jar="BuildTools.jar"
path="${directory}${jar}"
output="/var/www/html/jars"
version=$1

if [[ ( -d "BuildData" ) || ( -d "Spigot" ) || ( -d "CraftBukkit" ) || ( -d "Bukkit" ) || ( -d "work" ) || ( -d "apache-maven-*" ) || ( -f "BuildTools.log.txt" ) ]]; then
    echo "Cleaning up..."
    rm -f -r BuildData/ Spigot/ CraftBukkit/ Bukkit/ work/ apache-maven-*/
    rm -f BuildTools.log.txt spigot-*.jar craftbukkit-*.jar vanilla-*.jar
fi

if [[ ! -f "${jar}" ]]; then
    echo "Downloading BuildTools..."
    wget https://hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/BuildTools/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/BuildTools.jar -O ${jar}
    chmod 775 ${jar}
fi

if [[ ! -z "${version}" ]]; then
    echo "Compiling jars for version ${version}..."
    java -jar ${jar} --rev ${version}
else
    echo "No version specified."
    echo "Compiling jars for the latest version..."
    java -jar ${jar} --rev latest
fi

if [[ ( -f "${directory}spigot-*.jar" ) || ( -f "${directory}craftbukkit-*.jar" ) ]]; then
    echo "Compilation is done. Re-organizing..."

    if [[ ! -z "${version}" ]]; then
        mv work/minecraft_server.*.jar ${directory}/vanilla-${version}.jar
    else
        mv work/minecraft_server.*.jar ${directory}/vanilla-latest.jar
    fi

    echo "Moving jars to the webserver..."
    mv ${directory}/vanilla-*.jar ${output}/
    mv ${directory}/spigot-*.jar ${output}/
    mv ${directory}/craftbukkit-*.jar ${output}/
else 
    echo "Could not re-organize, the jars hasn't been moved."
fi
```

**Edit:**
By executing the command: `./compile.sh 1.8.6`
For some reason the jarfiles aren't the right names.

[Result of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAl4l.png)

```
directory="$(pwd)/"
jar="BuildTools.jar"
path="${directory}${jar}"
output="/var/www/html/jars"
version=$1

if [[ ( -d "BuildData" ) || ( -d "Spigot" ) || ( -d "CraftBukkit" ) || ( -d "Bukkit" ) || ( -d "work" ) || ( -d "apache-maven-*" ) || ( -f "BuildTools.log.txt" ) ]]; then
    echo "Cleaning up..."
    rm -f -r BuildData/ Spigot/ CraftBukkit/ Bukkit/ work/ apache-maven-*/
    rm -f BuildTools.log.txt done.txt spigot-*.jar craftbukkit-*.jar vanilla-*.jar
fi

if [[ ! -f "${jar}" ]]; then
    echo "Downloading BuildTools..."
    wget https://hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/BuildTools/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/BuildTools.jar -O ${jar}
    chmod 775 ${jar}
fi

if [[ ! -z "${version}" ]]; then
    echo "Compiling jars for version ${version}..."
    java -jar ${jar} --rev ${version}
    echo "done" > done.txt
else
    echo "No version specified. Compiling jars for the latest version..."
    java -jar ${jar} --rev latest
    echo "done" > done.txt
fi

if [[ -f "done.txt" ]]; then
    echo "Compilation is done. Re-organizing..."

    for x in $(find ${directory} \( -name "*.jar" \)); do
        name=$(basename "${x}" ".jar")

        if [[ ${name} =~ ^(spigot|craftbukkit|minecraft_server)(-)?(.*)? ]]; then
            fullname="${name}.jar"

            echo "Jar found: ${fullname}, Moving to webserver..."

            if [[ ! -z "${version}" ]]; then
                outpath=${output}/${version}

                if [[ ! -d ${outpath} ]]; then
                    mkdir ${outpath}
                fi

                mv -f ${x} ${outpath}/${fullname}
            else
                outpath=${output}/latest

                if [[ ! -d ${outpath} ]]; then
                    mkdir ${outpath}
                fi

                rm -f -r ${outpath}
                mv -f ${x} ${outpath}/${fullname}
            fi
        fi
    done

    echo "Jars uploaded."
else
    echo "Could not re-organize, the jars hasn't been moved."
fi
```

And additionally, I would like to only have one file of each uploaded (Vanilla, Spigot, Craftbukkit), how do I do that?

Comment: Use `set -x` to see debugging output of your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the parenthesis inside your conditional expression, as well as trying to use globs on the wrong part of the expression (you can't use tests like that with globs).

To fix this you should do something like:

```
#set nullglob so non-matching globs return an empty string instead of an error
shopt -s nullglob
# assing the globs to arrays, note the quoting
spigotfiles=("${directory}"spigot-*.jar)
bukkitfiles=("${directory}"craftbukkit-*.jar)
# using an array without an index gives us the first item in the array
if [[ -f "$spigotfiles" || -f "$bukkitfiles" ]]; then
     ...
fi
```

The same error with parenthesis is in your cleanup-code too, which you can handle by just removing the parens (e.g. `[[ -d "dirname" || -d "fooname" ]]` )

You should also quote your variable expansions (i.e. `"${jar}"` etc.) in every case (like in a part of a command).

Also using `[[ ! -z $foo ]]` is the same as `[[ -n $foo ]]`

**Edit:**

Don't do

```
for x in $(find ${directory} \( -name "*.jar" \)); do
```

but instead just:

```
for x in *.jar; do
```

or if you want only your versioned files, you can do:

```
for x in *"-${version}.jar"; do
```

You still have the parens in the cleanup check, see the answer above for that.

And in the end of the script these lines are counterproductive:

```
            if [[ ! -d ${outpath} ]]; then
                mkdir ${outpath}
            fi
            rm -f -r ${outpath}
            mv -f ${x} ${outpath}/${fullname}
```

As you first create a dir, then remove it and then try to move things into it (hint: remove the `rm` line)

Comment: Please see the edit, I got some things working, but something else broken.

Comment: I am quite new to the Linux principles, but most of it does help a lot, which I thank for as said above, but I will try to rewrite it completely with your advise used. But I do want only Spigot-*.jar, Craftbukkit-*.jar and minecraft_server.*.jar and all uploaded to my webserver